# Current Active Processes file created on home folder

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu

there is a file in my home folder that is being created called "current-active-processes.tmp"

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:01 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:01 ksoftirqd/0
    6 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    7 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
    8 ?        00:00:00 migration/1
    9 ?        00:00:03 kworker/1:0
   10 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/1
   12 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/1
   13 ?        00:00:00 migration/2
   15 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/2
   16 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/2
   17 ?        00:00:00 migration/3
   19 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/3
   20 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/3
   21 ?        00:00:00 migration/4
   23 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/4
   24 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/4
   25 ?        00:00:00 migration/5
   27 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/5
   28 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/5
```

....

There is no way to get rid of it and after delete it reapears in a second. Is there a process that uses that file and is creating it every time? I have no clue, does anyone knows?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
lsof ~/current-active-processes.tmp
```

to see which process has that file open.